# OpenVPN with IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-20.04

I’m creating a server with OpenVPN to mask my IP address using this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-20-04) from DigitalOcean.

The setup worked perfectly when I configure Redirect All Traffic Through the VPN, all my accesses on sites with IPv4 display the VPS IP.

The problem occurs when I access sites that accept IPv6, in these cases the displayed address is that of my ISP.

Below the line (`/etc/sysctl.conf`)

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

I added the value

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

but nothing happened, still showing my ISP IPv6.

How do I also enable the use of the VPS IPv6?

---

**Update:**

I made these changes to the configuration files and it worked. But are they correct and secure?

**/etc/openvpn/server.conf**

```
server-ipv6 fd00:b956:4dc2::/64
push "route-ipv6 2000::/3"
push "dhcp-option DNS 2001:4860:4860::8888"
push "dhcp-option DNS 2001:4860:4860::8844"
```

**/etc/ufw/before6.rules**

```
# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] 
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to eth0
-A POSTROUTING -s fd00:b956:4dc2::/64 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE2a03:7720::1fe
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES
```

**/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

Comment: Can you post your server and client configuration files ? You can edit your server IP address for privacy. Although this looks like a **routing** issue to me. Assuming you have a Linux **client** machine, you could run `route6 -n` before and after starting the VPN and see if there is any difference. This is for IPv6. For IPv4: `route -n` and here for sure you should notice changes made to your routing table after starting the VPN, client-side.